# Question about objects learning javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FDvDY.jpg)

Trying to make an object why is the code blue and not red? under self ?
I get the following error

```
C:\Users\light\Desktop\js-bootcamp\objects\objects-101.js:7
    name: 'Gustavo',
    ^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at Object.compileFunction (node:vm:352:18)
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1033:15)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1069:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47
```

It's almost if the compiler thinks im making a variable

Comment: Please post code, data, and results as text, not screenshots. http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: Remember to read the [posting guidelines](/help/how-to-ask): don't show images of text, _show that text_ with appropriate [markup](/markdown) so it shows as code. The same goes for your errors: mark them as code because they're not paragraph text, and error positions usually rely on the text being monospaced. Having said that: can you show the code this happens in? Because the error is telling you that you didn't write proper JS _before_ the line it's showing (which we can from `Unexpected identifier`)